# converting csv to json with specifc conditions

Tags: python, csvtojson

I want to dump the values of csv to json with specific conditions,
here is code I have written:

```py
import json
import csv
csv_file = open("student_data.csv",'r')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, None)
#creating loop
for row in csv_reader:
    row['roll_number']= int (row['roll_number'])
     out=json.dumps(row,indent=2)
         jsonoutput = open(row['name']+"_"+str(row['no'])+'.json','w')
     jsonoutput.write(out)
jsonoutput.close()
csv_file.close()
```

This creates a json file for each row like from a csv like:

```
no,name,link        
1,pal,image.png 
2,nina,page.html    
3,ashi,image.jpg
```

to this expected output:

`pal_1.json`

```json
{
    "no": "1",
    "name": "pal",
    "link": {"photo": [{"abc": "image.png"}]}
}
```

`nina_2.json`

```json
{
    "no": "2",
    "name": "nina",
    "link": {"webpage": [{"abc": "page.html"}]}
}
```

`ashi_3.json`

```json
{
    "no": "3",
    "name": "ashi",
    "link": {"photo": [{"abc": "image.jpg"}]}
}
```

I tried with creating a dict like this but it didn't work because images can have different extension like jpg, png, jpeg.

```py
extension = {'.png': 'image'}
```

If my link is an image then it should be written as `"link": {"photo": [{"abc": "image.png"}]}` in this format, and if it's html , as `"link": {"webpage": [{"abc": "page.html"}]}`.

For html it's easy but for photo I'm bit confused because I can't directly specify every possible extension.

Comment: using 'mimetypes' you can find the file type, later on, based on your logic you can generate a link element. import mimetypes then this 'mimetypes.guess_type(row['link'])' will give you '('image/png', None)' output. You can classified it based on type and generate link accordingly.

Comment: You can read more details here https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to generate the output, you want from csv file.

I have imported mimetypes module. I am using Python 3.11 (latest release version). You can get more details [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html)

> import mimetypes

The CSV format and sample data used.

```
no,name,link
1 ,pal ,image.png
2 ,nina ,page.html
3 ,ashi ,image.jpg
3 ,test ,webpage.html
```

Python script:

```
import json
import csv
import mimetypes

csv_file =  open("student_data.csv", 'r')
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, None)
#print(csv_reader.fieldnames[2])
#creating loop
for row in csv_reader:
    row['no']= int(row['no'])
    #print(row)
    out=json.dumps(row,indent=2)
    print(mimetypes.guess_type(row['link']))
    linkFileType = mimetypes.guess_type(row['link'])[0].split('/')
    if('image' in linkFileType):        
        #Code with Link "link":{"photo":[{"abc":"image.png"}]} 
        print(linkFileType[0] +' is an Image type')                    
    else:
        #Code with link "link":{"webpage":[{"abc":"page.html"}]} 
        print(linkFileType[0] + ' is not an Image type')
    
    jsonoutput = open(row['name']+"_"+str(row['no'])+'.json','w')
    jsonoutput.write(out)
    print(out)
jsonoutput.close()
csv_file.close()
```

The output from the above script:

```
('image/png', None)
image is an Image type
{
  "no": 1,
  "name": "pal ",
  "link": "image.png"
}
('text/html', None)
text is not an Image type
{
  "no": 2,
  "name": "nina ",
  "link": "page.html"
}
('image/jpeg', None)
image is an Image type
{
  "no": 3,
  "name": "ashi ",
  "link": "image.jpg"
}
('text/html', None)
text is not an Image type
{
  "no": 4,
  "name": "test ",
  "link": "webpage.html"
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i made some changes and it's completely working thank you so much.